# Add value of column to SQL CONCAT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add the value of a column into a SQL CONCAT query to be able to update another column, let me demonstrate.

[image]

I need the value of the column "winner" and add it to my query, since what I want to accomplish is for the query to say `SELECT team2_name FROM x WHERE matchid = 1`.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
UPDATE tournament_matches 
SET match_id = 5 
WHERE team_name IN (
    SELECT CONCAT(@winner, '_name') 
    FROM get5_stats_matches 
    WHERE match_id = 1
);
```

But it doesn't affect any row since `CONCAT(@winner, '_name')` doesn't display *team2_name* which I need it to do.

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Why do you have `@` before `winner`? That's using a user-defined variable, not the table column.

Comment: Change `@winner` to `winner`.

Comment: If I just type winner + '_name' it will update 2 rows instead of just one.

Comment: Please post sample data from both tables and the desired result.

Comment: It should be `CONCAT(winner, '_name')`, not `winner + '_name'`

Comment: If it's updating 2 rows, you must have 2 rows with `team_name = 'team2_name'`

Comment: Are you trying to access a column named `team2_name`? You can't specify column names dynamically,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
UPDATE tournament_matches
SET match_id = 5
WHERE team_name IN (
    SELECT IF(winner = 'team1', team1_name, team2_name)
    FROM get5_stats_matches
    WHERE match_id = 1);
```

You can't use an expression to specify a column name directly.

Demos:

[Winner = Team1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ivAu7N693H21ho3XuYoexQ/2)

[Winner = Team2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ivAu7N693H21ho3XuYoexQ/1)

Comment: This seems to be working quiet good, however. It updates 2 rows when the SELECT IF statement goes to false, why is that?

Comment: There must be two rows with `team_name = 'Svertila'`. Which one should it update if it doesn't update both?

Comment: It's really just one row with team_name = 'Svartlila', I tried the `SELECT IF(winner = 'team1', team1_name, team2_name)` and it worked fine and gave back the correct results, when I add it to the whole query, it only works if team1 is the winner, if we change the column value so that team2 is the winner, 2 rows updates.

Comment: What is the team name of the 2nd row that's being updated?

Comment: I asked you to provide sample data, I'll ask again.

Comment: it is "Boisen".

Comment: So it's updating both the winner and loser?

Comment: Yes! https://gyazo.com/a33cfdbf489f0ee95e5c5c75d19c01ab

Comment: I'll try to explain it better. When I execute this query `UPDATE tournament_matches
SET match_id = 6
WHERE team_name IN (
    SELECT IF(winner = 'team1', team1_name, team2_name)
    FROM get5_stats_matches
    WHERE match_id = 4); ` and if winner (on match_id 4) equals **team2** then the correct row gets affected. But if winner (on match id 4) equals **team1** with that exact query, both of the rows on that screenshot gets affected.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Winner = team1: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ivAu7N693H21ho3XuYoexQ/2 Winner = team2: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ivAu7N693H21ho3XuYoexQ/1

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, it was literally a misspelling from my side, I had match_id instead of matchid in the end of the query which caused this...